# When self publishing, are you able to be artistic with the look of the printed word?

Tags: self-publishing

I have not yet published a book, but from reading many books over the years I have noticed that some authors will change the font, make things bold, or change the size of the words for increased emphasis or some other reason. I have also noticed that when reading electronic copies of the same works, that those artistic details are lost. .Is there a way to self publish and still be able to be artistic with the font and sizing of the words with the finished book?

Comment: Even in situations where you CAN control font, etc I strongly caution you against excessive playing with these parameters - in many cases you'll do little beyond making the work harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no. Electronic reading devices contain a limited number of resident fonts and have facilities for resizing which forces re-pagination. You will notice on Kindle that page numbers are estimated. Your work will be displayed on anything from a 40" LCD screen to a 4" Smartphone.

Formatting may be maintained and controlled by saving your work as a PDF with embedded fonts. However, this results in awkward output. If your book is represented by 1 page per screen on a small device the text may be so small as to render it unreadable. If you magnify the text is will not re-paginate. Subsequently you would need to scroll left and right to read each individual line.